# Send test IR commands

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-media-center

I have a Windows 7 computer to which I have a Dell IR receiver / transmitter hooked up to control a Cisco cable box for Windows Media Center.

I wanted to send test IR commands that would be outside of Media Center. The IR control through Media Center works perfectly but I want to see if I could send channel commands via command line or a program.

I came across `[CIRtest.exe][1]` which seems to be exactly what I am looking for but I can't find any documentation on how to run it. I've tried some CMD commands to run the exe but I am not sure where its located.

**How can I send IR commands to my Dell ehome receiver other than using Media Center?**

Comment: Here's some docs [google.com?q=cirtest.exe => msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564419(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Here's also app saying _can do any IR_ [WinLIRC @ SourceForge](http://winlirc.sourceforge.net/).